# Cannot change column width or add separate data labels in date specific bar chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have three bar charts of prices, with the x-axis set to the corresponding dates of those prices were received.

I need to show data labels from a separate column. I've tried the trick of adding a separate series with its width(es) set to 0, but for some reason for this type of graph that doesn't work, with the data labels always reverting to those of the first series (price).

Additionally, I can't increase the column widths. Here I've tried just reducing the gap width and changing the x-axis type to text-axis, but the former does nothing and the later messes up all the formatting as oppose to just increasing the column widths.

My Data is as such, three columns:

```
Project Price Date
Proj 1  1111  02/04/2013
Proj 2  3312  04/03/2013
Proj 3  2321  05/04/2014
```

Etc. I want bar charts of price, with the x-axis set to the date, and data labels set to Project. How can I accomplish this?

I currently have this:
[image]

But, I'd like it to look similar to this:
[image]

Comment: http://imgur.com/JLacGre

Comment: Above is what I have, next is what I want.

Comment: http://imgur.com/irWmhrg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that because it's a date, you have to create space for each day in between dates.

On top of this, because X-axis spacing must be constant, and tries to prevent overlap--for every series/project you add, your bars get thinner to create more mutually exclusive space.

To fix, set your "Overlap" to 100%.
***If you, however, have one date with multiple projects, this will hide all but one of them.***